# Haxe: "Int cannot be called"

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe

This one really got me for a while.

**Problem**

If you're reading this question, perhaps you're getting a mysterious "Int cannot be called" message

```
103: characters 22-29 : Int cannot be called
```

when you try to compile your Haxe application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Consider that you may be adding parentheses where they don't belong. For example, I have a class with public variable *level*

```
public var level(getLevel, setLevel):Int;
```

but was mistakenly referencing it, elsewhere, using parentheses

```
var charLevel:Int = c.level();
```

when I **should have omitted the parentheses**

```
var charLevel:Int = c.level;
```

Don't know why I did this, but I hope the information helps.